# A mix between <input> and <textarea>, or wrapping the <input>

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, textarea

Hi I need a user to edit small text, similar to a "tweet", about 100 characters, but unlike actual twitter tweets, new line character is not allowed, this is a single line. But another thing is that this edit field must be short horizontally, much less than the text length, about 20-40 characters wide. So textarea is much more convenient with two or three rows.

So basically I need a mix between a textarea and an input line. Or in other words an input line that is not scrolling but wrapping. Wrap long strings into two-three lines, but not allow any new line characters. How to achieve this?

This kind of input is needed for two reasons, one is that width of the parent element is fixed when on PC browser, and second is that it could be used in the phone browser (320 pixels wide).

Comment: please specify a reason to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to use a textarea and use JavaScript to filter the input, and CSS to fix the box dimensions.

Something like this:

```html
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

The JavaScript would monitor the key pressed, and only allow the character if it’s not a line feed and if the total length is less than your maximum.

```js
window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
function init() {
    var message=document.getElementById('message');
    message.onkeypress=checkMessage;
}
function checkMessage(event) {
    event=event||window.event;
    var key=event.which;
    var max=60;
    return key.code!=13 && this.value.length<max;
}
```

Comment: you can use `message.maxLength = 60` to limit the text instead

Answer (score 1):

Adding the CSS properties `overflow:hidden` and `resize:none` to a `<textarea>` should do the trick.

**JS to prevent ENTER**

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Comment: if I press ENTER in the textarea it still inserts a new line

Comment: A little javascript will take care of that. Check updated answer.

Comment: @exebook if this answer works please consider marking it as solved, or let me know how else I can help. cheers!